# Mass copy/paste with transform

Tags: transforms

So, I am working on this simple animation, and need to mass copy and paste some buildings:[image] each building is 7 units away from the last one horizontally. Is there any quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the array modifier in the modifiers tab.

Select the object you would like to copy and paste (or rather, make an array of) and then select the array modifier in the modifiers tab. Set the count value to however may copies you would like to make, then set the x, y, and z values under the relative offset check box (make sure it's checked) to however way you would like your object to be transformed.

Play around, experiment a little with the settings, and you will get the 
hang of it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Type the value "7" in the x value of the relative offset for your purpose, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Just a note, four spaces at the beginning of lines creates code formatting. I have removed this as code formatting is generally just better for code.